# Simple bar chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to create a simple bar chart according to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)
Here is my code and json file:
statistics.html

```
var xLPU=d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeBands([0, width]);
var yLPU=d3.scale.linear()
.range([height,0]);
var xLPUAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xLPU)
    .orient("bottom");

var yLPUAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yLPU)
    .orient("left");
var LPUdivision=d3.select("#LPU").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
d3.json("LPUdivision.json",function(data){
    xLPU.domain(data.map(function(d){return d.lpu;}));
    yLPU.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.amount; })]);
    LPUdivision.append("g")
    .attr("class","x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xLPUAxis);
    LPUdivision.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    LPUdivision.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar")
    .attr("x",function(d){return xLPU(d.lpu)})
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yLPU(d.amount); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yLPU(d.amount); });
```

LPUdivision.json

```
[
{"lpu":"lpu1","amount":"20"},
{"lpu":"lpu2","amount":"40"},
{"lpu":"lpu3","amount":"80"},
{"lpu":"lpu4","amount":"10"},
{"lpu":"lpu5","amount":"5"},
{"lpu":"lpu6","amount":"6"}
]
```

For some reason xLPU.rangeBand() returns infinity, can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to set `.rangeBands()` after setting the `.domain()`.

Comment: In case you might be interested, [nvd3](http://nvd3.org) has multiple bar charts using d3.js

Comment: Thanx to Lars Kotthof, works now, very strange that official example is wrong.

Comment: You can answer my question, I'll sure approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ordinal scales, you need to call `.rangeBands()` (or `.rangeRoundBands()`) after the domain has been set. When you call this function, the given range is divided according to the elements in the domain -- if the domain has not been set, there's only one band that covers, as you found out, infinity.